# What is the difference between str.join() and str().join() in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I'm using Python3, I'm trying to join list items into a string, I found that when I try `str().join(lst)` I successfully get the list items as a string but when I do this `str.join(lst)` I get:

> TypeError: descriptor 'join' requires a 'str' object but received a
> 'list'

What is the difference between `str` and `str()` in this case?

Comment: Occasionally you may actually see `str.join(lst)` if so watch out for code that assigns to `str` elsewhere e.g. `str = "hello"`.  This "works" but is almost always a mistake.  See also [Why can you assign values to built-in functions in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31865529/8379597)

Comment: `str()` is just a fancy obfuscation for `''`, i.e. creates an empty string. You could simply call `''.join(...)`. Whereas `str.join(...)` is an unbound reference to the string join() function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str` is a class. `str()` invokes that class's constructor and returns an instance of that class.

You typically want something like this anyway:

```
", ".join(...)
```

I suppose `str().join(...)` is the equivalent of `"".join(...)`, but the latter is clearer to most Python developers.

Comment: +1. One might wanna add that the classmethod `str.join` additionally takes the separator string as the first argument, and only then the list as the second. That's where the TypeError comes from.

Answer (score 2):

`join(list)` is a class method of `str` class. `str()` is constructing an object (empty string object) of `str` class and it also have `join` method.

`str().join(['abc', 'def'])` will return `abcdef` and it is equivalent to `''.join(['abc', 'def'])`. What `str()` does it creating empty string object.

Class method `join` can also be used to generate the same result. 
You can use `str.join('', ['abc', 'def'])` to generate the same output.

In summary, `'string'.join([string list])` is equivalent to `str.join('string', [string list])`